# Are the letters shown in the Dwarf Fortress loading screen random?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When you load up something in DF, there is a point where a bunch of colored letters are shown. I was wondering if each individual letter actually means something, or is it just random space filler until it reaches 100%.
<sub>Screenshot – click the image below to view the original, full-sized image:</sub>

[image]

Comment: It helps if you mention the version of DF. The versions tend to change a lot over time.

Comment: @Ids the most recent. I think its 40.11 or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are quite meaningful:

Each letter represents a loaded monster, and the letter used is the monster in question.

Comment: Any way I could tell which one is which?

Comment: @Dgrin91: To some extent you can tell by the symbol, color and grouping. For instance, knowing that the pink 'p' in the approximate middle of the second line is a pig (it's a fairly striking combo), you can puzzle out that the ones around it are other barnyard animals. Also, many animals are grouped as "animal, animal man, giant animal", often rendered as "aaA".